# How to make Mule 3 display full stack traces

Tags: mule

I had an exception where I got this shortened trace:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3677)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2749)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:494)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

I then put this in "**`log4j.properties`**" and it didn't help:

```
log4j.logger.org.mule=DEBUG
```

I also failed with the second suggestion (and I suspect I'm not doing it right):

```
$ ./mule -Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3INSTALL/Controlling+Mule+From+Startup), arguments are passed from the command line to Mule that way:

```
$ ./mule -M-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true
```

ie. prefixed by **-M**.

Comment: How do you do this if you are running Mule from Mule Studio?

Comment: Add `-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true` to the VM parameters of your app's launcher.

Answer (score 1):

By default Mule filters out some internal class references from stacktraces to produce a more readable output.you can follow the given link for proper understanding..https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-mule-stacktraces

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is more related about how to configure the verbose on exceptions in Mule Studio, but if you want to configure this directly in the Mule ESB server too, You can add `wrapper.java.additional.n entries` to the **wrapper.conf** file in the **/conf** directory under the Mule installation directory. This wrapper.conf contains all the parameters sent to Mule at start time:

i.e. `wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true`

Just make sure the index of the **wrapper.java.additional.** parameter is not used for other one.

To pass the arguments at the command line by adding the -M switch.

i.e. `MULE_HOME/bin/mule -M-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true`

For Anypoint Studio Deployment:

Right click on the Project Root in Studio,  select "Run As" -> "Run Configuration" -> "Argument" tab, append the arguments in the VM arguments window,

```
i.e.  -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true
```

For Running Mule as Maven application:

You can pass the command line argument as

```
i.e. mvn package -Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true
```

For Cloudhub Deployment:

You can pass the command line argument by adding them as Properties in the Deployment -> Settings -> Properties section